# apigee - what does "java.net.NetPermission specifyStreamHandler" mean?

Tags: java, apigee

> {"fault":{"faultstring":"Execution of set-target-url failed on line 49
>   with error: access denied (\"java.net.NetPermission\"
>   \"specifyStreamHandler\")","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.javascript.ScriptExecutionFailedLineNumber"}}}

I have noticed I am getting it when I send the request to target URL, or, when try to use the `httpclient` object in `_sendMsg()` method.

sometimes it works fine sometimes it doesn't.

```
function logger() {
    var log_levels = {
        "emerg": 0       
    }

    function log(msg, log_level) {
        if (!log_level) {
            log_level = "debug";
        }

        if (typeof msg != "string") {
            msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
        }

        var log_entry = this._getSystemInfo();
        log_entry["msg"] = "33333 "+msg;
        log_entry["log_level"] = log_levels[log_level];

        this._sendMsg(log_entry)
    }


    //private
    function _sendMsg(log_entry) {
        if (typeof log_entry != "string") {
            log_entry = JSON.stringify(log_entry);
        }
        print(log_entry)
        var logging_gateway_service_url = this._getContext().getVariable("configs.logging-gateway-service.targetUrl");
        var req = new Request("http://" + logging_gateway_service_url, "POST", {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, log_entry);
        httpClient.send(req);
    }

    function _getContext() {//made for mocking in tests
        return context;
    }

    function _getSystemInfo() {
        var systemInfo = {
            "organization.name": this._getContext().getVariable("organization.name")
         }
        return systemInfo;
    }

    return {
        log: log,
        _sendMsg: _sendMsg,
        _getSystemInfo: _getSystemInfo,
        _getContext: _getContext
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the lines of code involved? Apigee Javascript code is executed inside a JVM runtime.

Comment: @SantanuDey I have pasted the code

Answer (score 0):

@yuria Two things you can possibly suspect

1. Apigee has some restrictions in place for a script / code running
   inside a message processor. What is your target URL set to? If you
   are trying to target the same MP's management URL from you script
   that could be an issue. Please try with a completely external URL and observe
   if you can reproduce the issue.
2. If #1 is not the issue 2nd thing I
   can think of is to restart both of your MPs.